# Accessing array index from joined table yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, yii2

Hello I have two tables schead and scstock which I joined and put in an array that looks like this.

```
return static::find()
          ->select('scstock.*')
          ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
          ->where([ 'schead.curriculumcode' => $currcode,
            'schead.terms' => '1ST', 
            'schead.styear' => 1])
          ->asArray()
          ->all();
```

Now when I go to the view I can't access the columns that are in the schead table in this case the index is `section` see the screenshot below:
[image]

The question is how do I access the columns in the schead table in that array index?
And then what I did in the view is this

```
 <?php foreach($firstyearfirstterm as $subjects):?>
 <?= $subjects['section']?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But it resulted in the screenshot below. Then it was also suggested to do this when trying to output the section.

```
 foreach($subjects as $subject){
                                    echo $subject->schead->section;
                              }
```

But then I got this.

[image]

I need help trying to solve this, I am very new to yii framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the columns only for the `scstock` table. Use the following for the select statement:

```
->select(['scstock.*', 'schead.*'])
```